# Can I store Payment Reference Number of an order,which are generated by CCAVENUE in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, payment, reference

I want to add Payment reference number for particular order. I will use **Magento-2.1** and frontend is in **Angular**. Suppose `CCAVENUE` sending payment link to customer for placed order.

- `CCAVENUE` generate payment reference number [`transaction_id`].

Can I store this payment reference number to  **Magento** order?

Comment: Yes, you can store transaction id in Magento order.

Comment: Mage order?????

Comment: yeah, Magento order

Comment: Order is placed through angular frontend.

Comment: yeah, you can store it in order_data

Comment: u mean  sales_order?

Comment: Yeah sales_order

Comment: I will add transaction id manually?